# "more than" vs. "greater than"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

What is the application of "more than" and "greater than" and their difference? What is their opposite? "less than" and "lesser than"?

for example for quantities like "width" or "area" which is used?

Comment: This might help : http://magoosh.com/gmat/2012/gmat-comparisons-more-vs-greater-and-less-vs-fewer/

Comment: and http://www.gmatpill.com/more-than-vs-greater-than-vs-less-than-fewer-than/

Comment: @VarunKN Thank you, however, I still don't know Size and Dimensions are countable or uncountable. I guess they are uncountable and I should use more and less.

Comment: Now that's a different question. Yes, it can be tricky. Try this : http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/size_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of

> **more** than

can be either

> **less** than
>   **fewer** than

depending on if something is **countable** or not, both phrases meaning **not as much**

> I drank **less than** a pint of milk
>   The restaurant had **fewer than** twenty people

The opposite of

> **greater** than

is

> **less** than

and has more of a **mathematical** favour about it: **<**, **>**

but the opposite could also be

> **smaller** than

if **greater** is used in the context of **size**

> Its size was **greater** than a mountain, but **smaller** than a planet.

but in those cases **bigger** is usually used instead of **greater**